# Vote with Gnosis Safe assets on Snapshot

Tags: gnosis-safe

Using the Web-Version of Gnosis Safe on Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127.

Having issues voting on *https://snapshot.org/* with Gnosis Safe assets on Gnosis Chain.
Signed in with Gnosis Safe via Walletconnect on *https://snapshot.org/#/delegate/* and delegated voting power to one of my EOA (MetaMask) account. The delegation has been confirmed on the Gnosis Safe (setDelegate transaction successful deployed).

After signing in on Snapshot with my EOA, it shows that I do not have sufficient voting power (which would be true for the EOA, however should be supposed to also count the assets in my Safe).

If I do the same with my Gnosis Safe account, it ownly runs "signing Message" transaction which leads to no votes being counted.

Did basic troubleshooting actions already (hard refresh browser, clearing cache, cookies, history).

Safe support team asked to post this question here. Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: it seems like a question for the snapshot team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshot delegate is only available on mainnet atm. https://docs.snapshot.org/gnosis-safeThanks